# How to use Google Natural Language with portuguese sentences, with gcloud CLI tool?

Tags: nlp, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-nl

I used this command:

**"gcloud ml language analyse-syntax --language=pt-br --content="Capítulo"**

and get this error:

ERROR: (gcloud.ml.language.analyze-syntax) Failed to read command line argument [--content=Cap\xedtulo] because it does not appear to be valid 7-bit ASCII.

gcloud ml language to be analyze-syntax --content=Cap\sedtulo
                                                     ^invalid character

But, if I use the demo tool (https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/?hl=pt-br), I get the correct response.

Why? How to use Google Natural Language with accented languages like portuguese or spanish?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am with Google Cloud Platform Support.

Apparently this might be an internal issue and that's why I will raise it with the proper investigative team. I will post a comment to my answer, linking the proper [Google Public Issue Tracker page](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/).

**Why?**

You can get more information about this error if you run the following command:

```
gcloud ml language analyze-syntax --content-file=analyze_test.txt --verbosity=debug
```

where `analyze_test.txt` contains

> Capítulo

The thrown error:

```
File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/apitools/base/protorpclite/messages.py", line 1541, in validate_element
    raise validation_error
ValidationError: Field content encountered non-ASCII string 'Cap\xc3\xadtulo\n': 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

suggests that somewhere along the way, encoding specification is lacking when the `gcloud ml` communicates with this library. Missing the encoding, the library *protects itself* against unknown characters (other than [7-bit ASCII characters](http://www.neurophys.wisc.edu/comp/docs/ascii/#table)).

---

As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml/language/analyze-syntax) suggests, one should use this command *for experiments, or for extremely short text*. In production, or in an application one should use i.e. the [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/apis).

Comment: [This link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71527718) leads to the filed public issue.